# Access: Bottom 20% of Performers by Average Performance?

Tags: ms-access, average, percentage, percentile

So I have been tasked with using an Access database to find the bottom 20% of performers every week.  I am having a mental block though on how to do that given that every worker will essentially have 5 days worth of data, so I need to find the bottom 20% by average and not by individual days.  Is there a way to do this in Access?  Or would I have to take an excel database and find an average for each person via something like a pivottable then export that to Access to find the bottom 20%?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you add more detail about your data structure and what you've tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to filter to get the correct date range, then group by person to get an average score for that week, then you can use the `TOP ## PERCENT` statement in to get the 20% you need

```
Select TOP 20 PERCENT Person, AverageScore
FROM (
    Select Person, AverageScore = Average(Score)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YourDateColumn > dateadd("d", -7, date) and YourDateColumn <= date
    Group By Person
    ) avgs
order by AverageScore desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I believe this will do the trick.  Though the managers met a little while ago and decided against using the top and bottom % and are going with straight cut off points which were already built into my program.  XD

Comment: @Rich well c'est la vie. You have this for next time at least